# Smart Card relogin failed with message "validation of viewstate MAC failed" After executed "ClearAuthenticationCache"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, authentication, iis, smartcard

In my ASP.NET web application, I use smart card to login.  After logged out, I want to make the IIS prompt pin if login again.  So the following command is run -

```
document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache');
```

It does prompt the selection of certificate.  However after pick up the correct certificate, "Validation of viewstate MAC failed" error is thrown.

Machine key has been set in web.config.  I test it in a single server.

Can this be fixed?

Is there another way to force relogin without executing the above command?

The error log is like -

```
<error    application="/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT"    host="MMM809-PB8GMTC"    type="System.Web.UI.ViewStateException"    message="Invalid viewstate. &#xD;&#xA;&#x9;Client IP: 127.0.0.1&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;Port: 64307&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;Referer: https://localhost:48044/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;Path: /Account/Login.aspx&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;ViewState: 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"    detail="System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that &lt;machineKey&gt; configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information. ---&gt; System.Web.UI.ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. &#xD;&#xA;&#x9;Client IP: 127.0.0.1&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;Port: 64307&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;Referer: https://localhost:48044/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;Path: /Account/Login.aspx&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;ViewState: 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&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString, Purpose purpose)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter, String serializedState, Purpose purpose)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState()&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)&#xD;&#xA;   at ASP.account_login_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\277b2a97\3a0c0b22\App_Web_tivyflc5.0.cs:line 0&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)"    time="2017-08-14T21:15:21.9999720Z"    statusCode="500"    webHostHtmlMessage="&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;html&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;head&gt;&#xD;&#xA;        &lt;title&gt;Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that &amp;lt;machineKey&amp;gt; configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.&lt;/title&gt;&#xD;&#xA;        &lt;meta name=&quot;viewport&quot; content=&quot;width=device-width&quot; /&gt;&#xD;&#xA;        &lt;style&gt;&#xD;&#xA;         body {font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;;font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} &#xD;&#xA;         p {font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;;font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}&#xD;&#xA;         b {font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;;font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}&#xD;&#xA;         H1 { font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;;font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }&#xD;&#xA;         H2 { font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;;font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }&#xD;&#xA;         pre {font-family:&quot;Consolas&quot;,&quot;Lucida Console&quot;,Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}&#xD;&#xA;         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}&#xD;&#xA;         .version {color: gray;}&#xD;&#xA;         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}&#xD;&#xA;         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }&#xD;&#xA;         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {&#xD;&#xA;          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }&#xD;&#xA;         }&#xD;&#xA;         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {&#xD;&#xA;          pre { width: 280px; }&#xD;&#xA;         }&#xD;&#xA;        &lt;/style&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;/head&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;body bgcolor=&quot;white&quot;&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;            &lt;span&gt;&lt;H1&gt;Server Error in '/' Application.&lt;hr width=100% size=1 color=silver&gt;&lt;/H1&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;            &lt;h2&gt; &lt;i&gt;Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that &amp;lt;machineKey&amp;gt; configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.&lt;/i&gt; &lt;/h2&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;            &lt;font face=&quot;Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif &quot;&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;            &lt;b&gt; Description: &lt;/b&gt;An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;            &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;            &lt;b&gt; Exception Details: &lt;/b&gt;System.Web.HttpException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that &amp;lt;machineKey&amp;gt; configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;            &lt;b&gt;Source Error:&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;            &lt;table width=100% bgcolor=&quot;#ffffcc&quot;&gt;&#xD;&#xA;               &lt;tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;                  &lt;td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;                      &lt;code&gt;&lt;pre&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;[No relevant source lines]&lt;/pre&gt;&lt;/code&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;                  &lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;               &lt;/tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;            &lt;/table&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;            &lt;br&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;            &lt;b&gt; Source File: &lt;/b&gt; c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\277b2a97\3a0c0b22\App_Web_tivyflc5.0.cs&lt;b&gt; &amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp; Line: &lt;/b&gt; 0&#xD;&#xA;            &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;            &lt;b&gt;Stack Trace:&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;            &lt;table width=100% bgcolor=&quot;#ffffcc&quot;&gt;&#xD;&#xA;               &lt;tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;                  &lt;td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;                      &lt;code&gt;&lt;pre&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. &#xD;&#xA;&#x9;Client IP: 127.0.0.1&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;Port: 64307&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;Referer: https://localhost:48044/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;Path: /Account/Login.aspx&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;ViewState: 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]&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;[HttpException (0x80004005): Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that &amp;lt;machineKey&amp;gt; configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.]&#xD;&#xA;   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +153&#xD;&#xA;   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString, Purpose purpose) +912&#xD;&#xA;   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter, String serializedState, Purpose purpose) +61&#xD;&#xA;   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +309&#xD;&#xA;   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +367&#xD;&#xA;   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +46&#xD;&#xA;   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +9527&#xD;&#xA;   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +355&#xD;&#xA;   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +75&#xD;&#xA;   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +70&#xD;&#xA;   ASP.account_login_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\277b2a97\3a0c0b22\App_Web_tivyflc5.0.cs:0&#xD;&#xA;   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +798&#xD;&#xA;   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp;amp; completedSynchronously) +91&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/pre&gt;&lt;/code&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;                  &lt;/td&gt;&#xD;&#xA;               &lt;/tr&gt;&#xD;&#xA;            &lt;/table&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;            &lt;br&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;/body&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/html&gt;&#xD;&#xA;">    <serverVariables>      <item        name="ALL_HTTP">        <value          string="HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL:no-cache&#xD;&#xA;HTTP_CONNECTION:Keep-Alive&#xD;&#xA;HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH:1369&#xD;&#xA;HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE:application/x-www-form-urlencoded&#xD;&#xA;HTTP_ACCEPT:text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*&#xD;&#xA;HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gzip, deflate&#xD;&#xA;HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:en-US&#xD;&#xA;HTTP_HOST:localhost:48044&#xD;&#xA;HTTP_REFERER:https://localhost:48044/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f&#xD;&#xA;HTTP_USER_AGENT:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko&#xD;&#xA;" />      </item>      <item        name="ALL_RAW">        <value          string="Cache-Control: no-cache&#xD;&#xA;Connection: Keep-Alive&#xD;&#xA;Content-Length: 1369&#xD;&#xA;Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded&#xD;&#xA;Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*&#xD;&#xA;Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate&#xD;&#xA;Accept-Language: en-US&#xD;&#xA;Host: localhost:48044&#xD;&#xA;Referer: https://localhost:48044/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f&#xD;&#xA;User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko&#xD;&#xA;" />      </item>      <item        name="APPL_MD_PATH">        <value          string="/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT" />      </item>      <item        name="APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH">        <value          string="C:\JJJ\FFF2v2\DEV_MVC\Prototype\FFF.Admin\FFF2\" />      </item>      <item        name="AUTH_TYPE">        <value          string="" />      </item>      <item        name="AUTH_USER">        <value          string="" />      </item>      <item        name="AUTH_PASSWORD">        <value          string="*****" />      </item>      <item        name="LOGON_USER">        <value          string="" />      </item>      <item        name="REMOTE_USER">        <value          string="" />      </item>      <item        name="CERT_COOKIE">        <value          string="a4b74eb1dcfd75b321ea17b5486687b91900001103c95854d42f7d0345d17c83" />      </item>      <item        name="CERT_FLAGS">        <value          string="1" />      </item>      <item        name="CERT_ISSUER">        <value          string="C=US, O=Entrust, OU=Certification Authorities, OU=Entrust Managed Services SSP CA" />      </item>      <item        name="CERT_KEYSIZE">        <value          string="256" />      </item>      <item        name="CERT_SECRETKEYSIZE">        <value          string="1024" />      </item>      <item        name="CERT_SERIALNUMBER">        <value          string="49-4a-2a-2c" />      </item>      <item        name="CERT_SERVER_ISSUER">        <value          string="CN=localhost" />      </item>      <item        name="CERT_SERVER_SUBJECT">        <value          string="CN=localhost" />      </item>      <item        name="CERT_SUBJECT">        <value          string="C=US, O=U.S. Company, OU=Dept of EE, OU=CIV, CN=GGGG UUU (Affiliate) + OID.0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1=15001003062231" />      </item>      <item        name="CONTENT_LENGTH">        <value          string="1369" />      </item>      <item        name="CONTENT_TYPE">        <value          string="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />      </item>      <item        name="GATEWAY_INTERFACE">        <value          string="CGI/1.1" />      </item>      <item        name="HTTPS">        <value          string="on" />      </item>      <item        name="HTTPS_KEYSIZE">        <value          string="256" />      </item>      <item        name="HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE">        <value          string="1024" />      </item>      <item        name="HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER">        <value          string="CN=localhost" />      </item>      <item        name="HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT">        <value          string="CN=localhost" />      </item>      <item        name="INSTANCE_ID">        <value          string="2" />      </item>      <item        name="INSTANCE_META_PATH">        <value          string="/LM/W3SVC/2" />      </item>      <item        name="LOCAL_ADDR">        <value          string="127.0.0.1" />      </item>      <item        name="PATH_INFO">        <value          string="/Account/Login.aspx" />      </item>      <item        name="PATH_TRANSLATED">        <value          string="C:\JJJ\FFF2v2\DEV_MVC\Prototype\FFF.Admin\FFF2\Account\Login.aspx" />      </item>      <item        name="QUERY_STRING">        <value          string="ReturnUrl=%2f" />      </item>      <item        name="REMOTE_ADDR">        <value          string="127.0.0.1" />      </item>      <item        name="REMOTE_HOST">        <value          string="127.0.0.1" />      </item>      <item        name="REMOTE_PORT">        <value          string="64307" />      </item>      <item        name="REQUEST_METHOD">        <value          string="POST" />      </item>      <item        name="SCRIPT_NAME">        <value          string="/Account/Login.aspx" />      </item>      <item        name="SERVER_NAME">        <value          string="localhost" />      </item>      <item        name="SERVER_PORT">        <value          string="48044" />      </item>      <item        name="SERVER_PORT_SECURE">        <value          string="1" />      </item>      <item        name="SERVER_PROTOCOL">        <value          string="HTTP/1.1" />      </item>      <item        name="SERVER_SOFTWARE">        <value          string="Microsoft-IIS/7.5" />      </item>      <item        name="URL">        <value          string="/Account/Login.aspx" />      </item>      <item        name="HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL">        <value          string="no-cache" />      </item>      <item        name="HTTP_CONNECTION">        <value          string="Keep-Alive" />      </item>      <item        name="HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH">        <value          string="1369" />      </item>      <item        name="HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE">        <value          string="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />      </item>      <item        name="HTTP_ACCEPT">        <value          string="text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*" />      </item>      <item        name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING">        <value          string="gzip, deflate" />      </item>      <item        name="HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE">        <value          string="en-US" />      </item>      <item        name="HTTP_HOST">        <value          string="localhost:48044" />      </item>      <item        name="HTTP_REFERER">        <value          string="https://localhost:48044/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f" />      </item>      <item        name="HTTP_USER_AGENT">        <value          string="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" />      </item>      <item        name="IS_LOGIN_PAGE">        <value          string="1" />      </item>    </serverVariables>    <queryString>      <item        name="ReturnUrl">        <value          string="/" />      </item>    </queryString>    <form>      <item        name="__EVENTTARGET">        <value          string="" />      </item>      <item        name="__EVENTARGUMENT">        <value          string="" />      </item>      <item        name="__VIEWSTATE">        <value          string="/12345678905NTIyMjMwNQ9kFgJmD2QWBAIBD2QWAgIKD2QWAgIBD2QWAmYPDxYEHgRUZXh0BSFSZWxlYXNlIDEwLjguMTogTG9jYWwgRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnQeB1Zpc2libGVnZGQCAw9kFgQCBQ88KwANAQAPFgIeC18hRGF0YUJvdW5kZ2RkAggPZBYGZg8PFgIfAAVPRW50ZXIgeW91ciB1c2VybmFtZSwgcGFzc3dvcmQsIG9yIGluc2VydCB5b3VyIFBJViBDYXJkIGFuZCBjaGVjayB0aGUgYm94IGJlbG93LmRkAgMPDxYCHwFnZGQCBA8PFgIfAWdkFgQCAQ8PFgIfAAVyUGxlYXNlIGluc2VydCB5b3VyIFBJViBDYXJkIGludG8geW91ciB3b3Jrc3RhdGlvbidzIGNhcmQgcmVhZGVyLCBhbmQgY2xpY2sgdGhlICdMb2dpbiBXaXRoIFBJViBDYXJkJyBidXR0b24gYmVsb3cuZGQCAw8PFgQfAGUfAWhkZBgBBR5fX0NvbnRyb2xzUmVxdWlyZVBvc3RCYWNrS2V5X18WAwUeY3RsMDAkTWFpbkNvbnRlbnQkQ2hlY2tCb3hQT0FNBRNjdGwwMCRJQ2FuY2VsJGN0bDAxBRNjdGwwMCRJQ2FuY2VsJGN0bDAzLS/FM9A6VVP18RwsD2IC7Rg/xts=" />      </item>      <item        name="__EVENTVALIDATION">        <value          string="/wEd22ySLZWi7YKvA222Ghxs5i/gdgSlZayxK222UBT+LqAPEQXWHOQW8ippJhMjXGvdzYpORp2222qSEthdF2fKQKT3+gipLj222/Qq2a+jO7Sdw69cI2b222177ItZkMEJTRS1W7nAjfkkQn8EsSZ7gk+2222hijOlATDRMbKYdiBI3/E22xjXszlb3Zt02VABJbFgx61+Zyi3222hiddMDq06RoW1pAPcBZaBtZ5cjbMK6KAeH/L222TzxQxNLc5z7Kkxgno0Zw1m8I6glrnouRiEmp0Grg==" />      </item>      <item        name="ctl00$RegistrationID">        <value          string="" />      </item>      <item        name="ctl00$MainContent$hfreadconsent">        <value          string="yes" />      </item>      <item        name="ctl00$MainContent$UserLogin$UserName">        <value          string="" />      </item>      <item        name="ctl00$MainContent$UserLogin$Password">        <value          string="" />      </item>      <item        name="ctl00$MainContent$btnLoginWithSmartCard">        <value          string="Login With Smart Card" />      </item>      <item        name="ctl00$MainContent$CheckBoxPOAM">        <value          string="on" />      </item>      <item        name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR">        <value          string="CD85D8D2" />      </item>    </form>    <cookies>      <item        name="__AntiXsrfToken">        <value          string="58a7763a00bb42c286d47ac3ba217e64" />      </item>    </cookies>  </error>
```

Thanks

Edit 1: after executed `document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache');` I follow with `document.location.href="/";`.  Now the error goes away after reloaded the root Url.  However the reloaded page still caches the PIN. It allowed me to directly log in after selected the popped out certificate without further asked for a PIN number.  Do not know why "ClearAuthenticationCache" can not clear cached pin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://forums.iis.net/t/1205792.aspx) may answer my question -
The client just sends a certificate to the server. The server could force the client to resend the certificate. But server has no idea where the browser got the certificate from - that's some OS (or 3rd party provider) code that talks to the smart card. It's up to that provider to determine when the user should be re-prompted to access the smart card.