# Timed out web application with smart card authentication can only be logged in again after restart a new IE browser

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, smartcard

I have an asp.net web application hosted in IIS 8.5 using smart card to log in.  After timeout, I have to kill all IE browsers and launch a new one to get IIS to prompt for the certificate selection.

How can we allow users to re-login without launching a new browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://support.oneidentity.com/active-roles/kb/225324):

> NOTE: In order to force Internet Explorer to prompt with a new credential tile, use File | New Session

You must instruct your users to choose "New Session" from the "File" menu in order to get re-prompted.

You can also do this programmatically with Javascript:

```
document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");
```

Note that this will also clear out any session cookies.

Comment: Thanks @John Wu, I did it the Javascript way.  But I found out that this could not initialize another certificate.  I have another question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45683824/smart-card-relogin-with-validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-after-executed-cle.  Anything I missed there?

Comment: did not see IE 11 has a "New Session" from the "File" menu.